# SQL Triggers not working

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a trigger for sql

```
 CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER student
 BEFORE INSERT ON MEMBEROF
 FOR Each Row 
 WHEN (new.studentid != old.studentid )
 BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserted new year ');
 select extract(year from sysdate) 
 into :new.JOINED
 from dual;
 END;
/
```

This trigger is suppose to activate when a new entry is inserted and the year is changed to the current year

When i try to insert something in to the Memberof table this trigger is not activated.

My attempt was 
insert into memberof
 values (75234, 42, 1999);

Comment: A `WHEN` condition like this is pointless for an insert, assuming studentid is a required column anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old vs. new in your case returns false, because old is null  as no old value exists for every new data row.

I guess you are on oracle so you may try nvl() function to cover this or change your when condition simply to 1 = 1.

Comment: which one is the while condition?

Comment: Sorry, meant the condition after when.

Comment: is it possible to set a value null from the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try UPDATE instead of INSERT, there should be no old variable when call INSERT trigger.